# In visual studio, curly brace indentation seems to be off for python

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

While I was trying to use visual studio, it keeps appling weird styling that just seems off to me and throws off the indentation and coordination of each block of code.

[image]

Normally when I use ide's, the right curly brace would match up to the t, seeming to keep the end of the block inline like this EDIT: It also does this for brackets as well:

```
def graph(*arg):
test = {
    "data": [
        ],
    "layout": [
        ]
    }
```

How would I go about fixing this, I really like visual studio, but this kind of throws me off while i'm coding.

Comment: @Mark Ransom I am using them to define a dictionary, I will edit my code to show what I am trying to do and give more examples of this formatting error.

Comment: Curly braces in other languages are used to determine code blocks, and it makes sense for those to line up. Curly braces in Python are used for dictionaries, and the definition of a dictionary can't be at the same indentation level as the originating line - that would be a syntax error.

Comment: @Mark Ransom Ok, that makes sense. Thanks for clarifing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

As Mark Ransom stated on my post, according to him:

> Curly braces in Python are used for dictionaries, and the definition
>   of a dictionary can't be at the same indentation level as the
>   originating line - that would be a syntax error.